# Vector valued integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

Whenever I have been presented with integrals as (*), I have always used some sort of symmetry to get around actually calculating the integral. Now it just struck me that I have no idea how to "mechanically" calculate (*):

$$
\iiint \left(f(r)\hat{r}\right)\left(r^2\sin\phi\right) drd\phi d\theta \qquad \textbf{(*)}
$$
If it is necessary to define what region you are talking about for the question to make sense, I'll pick the unit sphere.

Would this have been the integral 
$$
\int f(x)\hat{x} dx
$$
I would have proceeded by moving the unit vector outside of the integral and calculated as usual

$$
\hat{x}\int f(x)\cdot dx = \hat{x}\left(F(x) +C\right)
$$

However, the problem with the integral is that the direction of $\hat{r}$ changes as $\phi$ and $\theta$ changes. Therefore I don't see how I could treat the unit vector as a constant and have no idea how to start with (*).

I apologize in  advance if this turns out to be a duplicate. [How to integrate a vector function in spherical coordinates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363780/how-to-integrate-a-vector-function-in-spherical-coordinates) verifies my gut feeling that $\hat{r}$ is not constant but doesn't make things much clearer for me than that.

Comment: But the unit vector $\hat x$ likewise changes with $x$? Why can you take it outside the integral?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding how that could be. In a Cartesian coordinate system, I would have thought that $\hat{x}$ never changes. It points in the same direction all the time.

Comment: Then perhaps you're using some other convention. Under the convention that I was applying, $\hat x$ is the unit vector that points along the position vector $x$. Clearly the position vector $x$ doesn't always point in the same direction.

Comment: I meant for $\hat{x}$ to be the direction of the x-axis in a fixed coordinate system. If there's is a less confusing way for me to write that, please, let me know.

Comment: If the coordinate system has more than one dimension, I'd write that as $e_x$. I'm now confused by the fact (which I hadn't noticed before) that you write $F(x)+C$, which looks as if $x$ here stands for a one-dimensional $x$ value and not for the position vector. If so, it's not clear to me why you'd be talking about vectors and axes at all.

Comment: $e_x$ it is then, thank you!

I was imagining something like a calculating the dipole moment for some charge density that lies completely on the x-axis. Say

$\int \vec{x} \left(3x^2\right) dx = \int \hat{x} \left(3x^3\right) dx$ or  $\int \hat{x}f(x)dx$  for some density in general.

Comment: That notation is rather confusing. I wouldn't use both $\vec x$ for the position vector and $x$ for its $x$ coordinate. If you need to refer to the $x$ coordinate, you can denote the position vector by $\vec r$.

Comment: Makes sense. My way is unnecessarily ambiguous. I'll try to adopt your approach in the future. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\hat{\mathbf{r}} = \sin\theta\cos\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{x}} + \sin\theta\sin\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{y}} + \cos\theta\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, you can write

$$
\iiint f(r)\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}\,r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta =
\iiint f(r) \left(\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{x}} + \sin\theta\sin\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{y}} + \cos\theta\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}\right)r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta
$$
which is the sum of three separate integrals:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}} \iiint f(r)\sin\theta\cos\phi\,r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta =
\hat{\mathbf{x}} \int f(r)\,r^2\,dr
\int\sin^2\theta\,d\theta
\int\cos\phi\,d\phi
$$
$$
\hat{\mathbf{y}}\iiint f(r)\,\sin\theta\sin\phi\,r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta =
\hat{\mathbf{y}} \int f(r)\,r^2\,dr
\int\sin^2\theta\,d\theta
\int\sin\phi\,d\phi
$$
$$
\hat{\mathbf{z}}\iiint f(r)\,\cos\theta\,r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta =
\hat{\mathbf{z}} \int f(r)\,r^2\,dr
\int\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta
\int d\phi
$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is the unit vector along the radial direction but $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$, $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$, and $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ are the Cartesian unit vectors.

(Note that I'm using the convention where the volume element is $r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta\,$.)

Comment: Note that there are [different conventions for spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Conventions); the OP's volume element was correct in one of them.

Comment: Fair enough. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the integral without being forced into rectangular coordinates at any point along the way?

Comment: @RobinNewhouse I'm afraid not. vectors exist on a tangent space, and only when you have rectangular coordinates do you actually get a "global" vector space via an isomorphism. Otherwise, you can't have position vectors